# Regular expression to search in html template

Tags: php, html, regex

I'm trying to find certain strings in a lot of files (cc. 2000 files).

What I basically need is to find any ID attribute in a html file except some certain ID's.

For example I want to find:

```
<a id="certain_id">sdfsdf</a>
```

But I want to exclude:

```
<a id="manage">Manage</a>
```

I only need a regular expression since I want to use it in Eclipse Search. But if I cannot I can make a php file to do it too.

Something like: id="(?!manage)" or similar. I don't want to replace anything I just want a list of elements in each file.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Why would you tag this `preg_match` if you're not going to implement it in PHP.

Comment: Don't use regex to search HTML, it's not a good fit.

Comment: nick: I mean if Eclipse's own search method does not have a proper regexp parser I would do it in php.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs using a regex to search **for** HTML isn't a great idea, but using a regex to search for text **in** an HTML file is fine. Text is text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This [worked for me](http://regexr.com?31co4):

```
id="(?!(manage|something)").*?"
^   ^                      ^  
|   |                      Any character (not greedy), followed by a quote
|   Negative lookahead to make sure there isn't manage|something and a quote
Match the id=" characters literally
```

Where `manage` and `something` are two IDs you don't want to match.

You could also use this to make it non-greedy:

```
id="(?!(manage|something)")[^"]+"
```

Answer (score 1):

Regular Expressions doesn't contain a natural "not" operator.

I believe a workaround exists, for instance you could do something like: id="(?!(undesirable1|undesirable2|undesirable3))"

It's been a little while since I did anything with regex, but I think that should work.

Edit: I think nick's answer is better

Comment: Well yours is the same ;) I knew it had something to do with the "look-forward" operator

Answer (score 0):

http://txt2re.com/ Best Tool Ever